# How to solve \$(X+Y)(\bar X+\bar Z)\$?

Tags: logic-gates, karnaugh-map, boolean-algebra

How do I solve
$$(X+Y)(\bar X+ \bar Z)$$

My take:

$$X \bar X+ X \bar Z+Y \bar X+Y \bar Z = X \bar Z+Y \bar X+Y \bar Z$$

But what after this? Its for sum of products

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 YZ¯ terms

Comment: If you did this correctly, your next step would be to factor out Y or Z'.. your choice.

Comment: @brhans Actually that was typo mistake. I have edited the question now

Comment: @Daniel How do I do that ? Pls help

Comment: What variable are you trying to isolate (solve for)?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'solve'. You have been given the product of sums to solve, so presumably you want to end up with the sum of products. Where to after a sum of products? Nowhere, if that's what's required.

Comment: What after this? Draw the Karnaugh map. Then you'll see it.

Comment: I always did these thinking of AND as a multiply operation and an OR as an addition operation. That way the distribution and factorization rules work the same.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to "solve". You have a formula of Boolean algebra that you have rearranged from a product of sums, to a sum of products.

To "solve" usually means to determine values for the variables. That requires some constraints. You need to turn the formula into an equation. And possibly you either need a additional equations, or to be given the values of some of the variables (so that only one remains unknown).

If we assume that the equation to be solved is this:

$$(X+Y)(\bar X+ \bar Z) = 1$$

In other words, "over what domain values is this formula true?" then the solution is a set: it consists of the set of \$X\$, \$Y\$ and \$Z\$ triplets which satisfy the equation.  We can obtain this solution set by writing down the truth table.

In an answer to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963269/boolean-expression-parser-truth-table-generation) I made a truth-table generating program, which we can just run from our Linux prompt:

```
$ txr -i truth.tl
1> (pretty-truth-table '((x or y) and (not x or not z)))
    x     y     z   | (x or y) and (not x or not z)
--------------------+------------------------------
    F     F     F   |               F
    F     F     T   |               F
    F     T     F   |               T
    F     T     T   |               T
    T     F     F   |               T
    T     F     T   |               F
    T     T     F   |               T
    T     T     T   |               F
nil
```

From this we can read out the solutions: all the \$X\$, \$Y\$ and \$Z\$ values from the variable columns, which have a `T` in the formula column.

Note that this is equivalent to just converting the formula to a sum of products.

Can we find a simpler formula which computes the same function over the variables? For that, we can use the Karnaugh Map technique, since there are only three variables. Since we have the truth table, it's easy to stuff the map:

```
     Z  0  1
X Y  +------
     |
0 0  |  0  0
     |
0 1  |  1  1
     |
1 1  |  1  0
     |
1 0  |  1  0
     |
```

And here is how we can play it:

```
     Z  0  1
X Y  +------
     |
0 0  |  0  0
     | +----+
0 1  | |1  1|    X'Y term  (Z is irrelevant)
     | +----+
1 1  |  1  0
     | 
1 0  |  1  0
     |


     Z  0  1
X Y  +------
     |
0 0  |  0  0
     |
0 1  |  1  1
     | +-+------ XZ' term (Y is irrelevant)
1 1  | |1| 0
     | | |
1 0  | |1| 0
     | +-+
```

We end up with \$\bar XY + X\bar Z\$. This is not really simpler than the original, because it still has four variables, three binary operators and two unary negations. We can draw the syntax trees to prove that the complexity is exactly the same:

```
  original:                      new:

        and                               or
      /     \                           /     \
   or        or                     and         and
  /   \     /   \                  /   \       /    \
  X   Y    not  not               not   Y      X    not
            |    |                 |                 |
            X    Z                 X                 Z
```

The raw, syntactic complexity of the best expression we can find with a Karnaugh map is exactly the same as the original.

That said, there is some semantic simplification in the sum-of-products representation in that it exposes clearly the regions of the XYZ variable domain. It gives use an "at a glance" view over that space, telling us where the expression is true, which is useful.

Comment: I suspect OP means "simplify"

Comment: I don't remember. But the answer I got from using deMorgan doesn't match your result.

Comment: @Daniel You can read off the De Morgan's result from the zeros in the Karnaugh map. `(x'y' + xz)'`.

Comment: that's not what your 'new' tree says

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to have two logically equivalent SOP forms like that

Comment: Although I guess the deMorgan result doesn't qualify because it has a global NOT in it.... heh

Answer (score 1):

You may need to convert this expression to a [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form).

$$X \bar Z+Y \bar X+Y \bar Z = X \bar Z (Y \bar Y) + ...$$
$$X \bar Z+Y \bar X+Y \bar Z = X Y \bar Z + X \bar Y \bar Z + ...$$

Answer (score 0):

This is something I struggled with too, seeing what to use. The easiest way to flip this over is to use deMorgan's Law:

$$ \begin{align} \\
\\
(X+Y)(\bar X+ \bar Z) &= \overline{\overline{(X+Y)}+\overline{(\bar X+ \bar Z)}} \\
&=\ldots\text{your work here}\ldots\\
\\
\end{align} $$

Comment: Now you can further distribute the inner not-s into the subexpressions: `(x + y)' -> x'y'`. And: `(x' + z')' -> xz`. See? These terms match what you can read from the Karnaugh map I drew up: equivalent to `(x'y' + xz)'`.